# fill_between doesn't work on windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, fill, between

I'm very new to Python Programming.
So, I'm trying to learn Python by a book called 'Python Crash Course'
But problem occured while I was working on using fill_between method in matplotlib. Here is my code.

---

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# Read min, max temperatures from the file
filename = 'sitka_weather_2014.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)

    dates, highs, lows = [], [], []
    for row in reader:
        current_date = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
        dates.append(current_date)

        high = int(row[1])
        highs.append(row[1])

        low = int(row[3])
        lows.append(low)

# plotting the data
fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(dates, highs, c='red', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(dates, lows, c='blue', alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(dates, highs, lows, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.1)

# deciding graph format
plt.title("Daily high and low temperature - 2014", fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('Numbers', fontsize=14)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.ylabel("Temperature (F)", fontsize=16)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=16)

plt.show()
```

---

The code above is trying to plotting the data of temperatures.
When I'm trying to run the code, pyCharm gives me this Traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pyCharm(sang)/highs_lows.py", line 28, in <module>
    plt.fill_between(dates, highs, lows, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.1)
  File "C:\Users\John Jung\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3000, in fill_between
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\John Jung\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1898, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\John Jung\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4779, in fill_between
    y1 = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_yunits(y1))
  File "C:\Users\John Jung\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py", line 2388, in masked_invalid
    condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Now I'm using PyCharm on Windows10, so it doesn't work.
But I ran this exactly same code on my mac last night, it worked
like a magic. Why does this do not work on Windows but Mac?
What's the fill_between's problem?

Thanks in advance guys!

update:
This is the sample code of sitka_weather_2014.csv

```
 AKST,Max TemperatureF,Mean TemperatureF,Min TemperatureF,Max Dew PointF,MeanDew PointF,Min DewpointF,Max Humidity, Mean Humidity, Min Humidity, Max Sea Level PressureIn, Mean Sea Level PressureIn, Min Sea Level PressureIn, Max VisibilityMiles, Mean VisibilityMiles, Min VisibilityMiles, Max Wind SpeedMPH, Mean Wind SpeedMPH, Max Gust SpeedMPH,PrecipitationIn, CloudCover, Events, WindDirDegrees
2014-1-1,46,42,37,40,38,36,97,86,76,29.95,29.77,29.57,10,8,2,25,14,36,0.69,8,Rain,138
2014-1-2,41,38,35,38,35,32,97,89,76,30.09,29.90,29.81,10,9,4,14,7,22,0.34,8,Rain,92
2014-1-3,39,36,34,38,36,33,100,97,93,30.43,30.32,30.10,10,9,2,8,3,,0.02,7,Rain,102
2014-1-4,43,38,34,35,33,31,97,82,62,30.43,30.32,30.20,10,10,10,20,6,25,0.00,6,Rain,107
2014-1-5,44,42,41,42,36,32,97,77,63,30.20,30.02,29.88,10,8,2,26,17,36,0.37,8,Rain,113
```

Comment: Have you tried running it outside of pyCharm IDE? Did you install Python by using anaconda, if so can you try it from a notebook? Also a 5-6 line sample of the `sitka_weather_2014.csv` would be great. Also which python exactly? I see that you have a username with special characters in it (`John Jung`). Last time I saw python 2 on Win. it struggled with the paths when they had special chars in them, but that's a different error.

Comment: I only tested it in pyCharm IDE. But, I ran it on my Mac with pyCharm IDE too, but it worked so well. Maybe something has to do with Window? There's a sample code above about sitka. Thanks!

Comment: I'll give it a go in an hour or two in win myself. Without PyCharm. This seems to be a recurring error with numpy whenever you have a list/array and do an `isinfinite` on it and that array has objects in it and not numbers (floats, ints ...). In your case this seems to be the `datetime` object. I would suggest perhaps as a prevention measure to use an MJD date format in the background and a `DateTimeTickFormatter` but I'll get back to you when I test it. See [this](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/type-error-with-python-3-2-and-version-1-1-1-of-matplotlib-numpy-error-td38784.html)

Comment: You should report about the exact matplotlib version you are using on your mac and on windows.

Comment: matplotlib version mac:2.0.2 windows:2.0.2, So they're same. If there's a difference between them is window uses python3.6.2, but mac uses python3.6.1

Answer (score 1):

It's as I "feared" in the comments. Numpy's `isinfinite` does not support objects. Because of that you will have to plot with the MJD (or whatever purely numerical date format you feel comfortable with) and use the tick formatter to make it look like a common-place date.

You can do that by doing

```
numdates = []
for date in dates:
     numdates.append(date.toordinal())
```

or

```
numdates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(dates)
```

then you can easily do

```
plt.plot(numdates, highs, c="red")  
plt.plot(numdates, lows, c="blue")    
plt.fill_between(numdates, high, lows, facecolor="blue", alpha=0.1)
plt.show()
```

of course now you will notice your x-axis is not in the easy-to-read format. Instead it's some big number representing the number of seconds since 1970 or something down those lines.

An easy fix for that that doesn't quite always work is to use the `plot_date` like so:

```
plt.plot_date(dates, highs, c="red", ls="-")  
plt.plot_date(dates, lows, c="blue", ls="-")    
plt.fill_between(numdates, high, lows, facecolor="blue", alpha=0.1)
plt.show()
```

Notice I declared explicitly the `linestyle` or `ls` for the `plot_date` because `plot_date` is actually a scatter-plot of points. Notice also how `dates` is used for the `plot_date` but `numdates` is used for `fill_between` and the plot still works. This is because `plot_dates` just tries guessing the `DateFormatter` for you in the background but the actual numbers are the same as from the top example.

Unfortunately formatting for the `plot_date` can sometimes be a bit off. In that case I recommend you just brave the [`DateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html) yourself, it's not that bad. If you want to hide the circles that get drawn for dates to just leave the line visible you can add a `marker=","` in the `plot_date` commands. This just draws a single pixel for the scatter point so it's hidden by the line, see more [here](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers). Also see other options for the `plot_date` func. [here](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot_date.html).

As to why this only happens sometimes - 9/10 chances it's numpy and python version related. This will pop up for numpy 1.12.1, matplotlib 2.0.2 and Python 3.6. I suspect that it would also happen for an older Python version (i.e. 2.7) and that it miiight not happen for some versions of numpy/matplotlib. All of this is speculation of course. As far as "why" goes - I think this is an good decision on numpy's part, but matplotlib should be reworked to hide this from the user. If you want you can try pinging them on [git](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib) to see what they have to say about it. If you don't want to, say so - I'm quite interested in seeing why.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ljetibo! But I'm really new to programming who has no experience over. What do you mean by Numpy's isinfinite? I just looked Numpy up and it says it's used collecting numbers or something.

Comment: Matplotlib uses numpy when it does things. One of the things it uses numpy for is to check if all the data is ok. This way if the user has accidentally left in an infinity the plot still looks nice and doesn't go crazy. They do that by checking the data to see if it `isinfinite` and then replace it with something they can draw. But `isinfinite` can be only used on numbers. It doesn't work on dates because logically there is no "infinite" date. In simpler terms. Do the answers work for you?

Comment: Wow! yes now I understand why it doesn't work on date. But why It worked on mac...? just because of the version difference? Btw, it's so helpful ljetibo, cheers!

Comment: Like I said, I can only guess why exactly. Because of the fact it works on MAC but doesn't work in win (Num 1.12.1, Py3.6, Mpl 2.0.2) or Ubuntu (Py2.7, Np 1.8.2, Mpl 2.0.2) makes it worthy to report the strange behavior to Matplotlib developers on github and ask them if this is intended behavior and if they're planing on changing it. I don't believe they are or will do it. They gave us `Formatters` and `plot_dates` for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

The error message here doesn't really help identify the root issue. The problem is in the code that pulls the data from the csv file. Here's the relevant part of that code:

```
dates, highs, lows = [], [], []
for row in reader:
    current_date = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
    dates.append(current_date)

    high = int(row[1])
    highs.append(row[1])

    low = int(row[3])
    lows.append(low)
```

When the data is read from the csv file, it's intially read in as a string. For each piece of data we're going to use, we need to convert it to the appropriate kind of data for plotting. So the date gets converted to a datetime object, and each temperature gets converted to an int. In your code, you've converted the high temperature to an int, but you haven't used that int. This line:

```
highs.append(row[1])
```

should be changed to:

```
highs.append(high)
```

If you make this change, I think you'll see the correct visualization. I wonder if `isinfinite()` was rejecting the string data?

Note: I'm the author of Python Crash Course, and I try to keep an eye out for posts like this. I really want to know that the projects are continuing to work for people, and update them if they are becoming out of date at all.